# JQuery button move sidemenu to left and resize content view to full width using animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I removed the previous question to slim it down a bit although it is searching for the same result. A code pen was created in hopes it would help although it is not showing up the same as when I run it and think it maybe because of javascript/bootstrap or some other library that is loaded. Here is basically what is happening and what I want to happen.

I need 2 panels a top fixed header and bottom content. The bottom will contain 2 horizontal panels. Left will contain a menu which will open/close when a button in the header panel is clicked. Tried the suggested answer using CSS but the panels would only align vertically not horizontally. Tied other CSS properties found in online searches and various JQuery suggestions. Currently the menu opens and closes on page load but when a link to a page is clicked the button in the header no longer has the event to fire to change the class to hide the menu.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
See code pen
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/1eagleusa/pen/JMWjxQ)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".js-togglemenu").on("click", function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-open");
});
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
}

#applicaitonHeader div {
max-height: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#MainMenuPanel {
top: 90px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
height: auto;
cursor: pointer;

transform: translateX(-100%);

transition: transform 0.3s;
}
#BodyContainer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.menu-open #MainMenuPanel {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="js-togglemenu" id="MenuShowHide">toggle menu</button>

<div id="applicaitonHeader" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
Header info goes here
</div>
<div id="MainMenuPanel" class="navbar-fixed-left">
Menu nodes go here
</div>
<div id="BodyContainer" class="container body-content">
Body content goes here
</div>
```

So you can all do this with css transform and transitions. using jquery animate is the old way of doing anmations. There is something to be said about javascript animations, but in this case, css is more then enough.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry so late in responding was out of the office for the holiday. I like your answer but when implementing it I am getting the same result as when I run your code snippet. The menu (text) slides in and out nicely but the body content is static above what would be the menu div. What I am trying to do is have a fixed top div which seems to be good and below that 2 div's or panels where 1 would be the menu sliding in and out and the other a main content which reacts to the menu either filling the remaining space or expanding to the complete width of the page. Is that possible with jsut CSS?